# there are different pages on github pages and on live server

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wrote a page in html, css and bootstrap and uploaded the page to github pages and what I looked at through vs code is different from what I look at on github pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tribute Page Steve Jobs
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<main id="main">
  <h1 id="title">Steve Jobs</h1>
  <p>American entrepreneur, inventor and industrial designer, widely recognized as a pioneer of the information
    technology era. Co-founder, Chairman of the Board of Directors and CEO of Apple Corporation. Co-founder and CEO of
    Pixar film studio.</p>
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://appleinsider.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/jobs_wallpapers.jpg" alt="Steve Jobs" />
    <figcaption id="img-caption">One of the best businessman in the world</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <section id="tribute-info">
    <h2>Steve Jobs Achievements</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>1976</strong> - along with Wozniak, he founded ‘Apple Computer Company’. Initially, the company mainly
        aimed at selling circuit boards. Same year, Wozniak invented the Apple I computer. </li>
      <li><strong>1985</strong> - difference of opinion between him and the company’s CEO John Sculley led to Jobs
        resigning from his own founded company. In the same year, he founded NeXT Inc. The company was famous for its
        technical strengths especially its object-oriented software development system.
      </li>
      <li><strong>1986</strong> - he bought the Graphics Group (later renamed Pixar) from Lucasfilm's computer graphics
        division. ‘Toy Story’ was the first animation film that was released after the acquirement.
      </li>
      <li><strong>1996</strong> - when Apple acquired NeXT Inc, he returned to his own co-founded company as a de facto
        chief in the company and was formally named interim chief executive.
      </li>
      <li>Under his guidance, a number of projects were disbanded. He introduced a whole new range of products which
        steeply increased the sales of the company, making it one of the electronic giants in the world.

      </li>
      <li><strong>Etc</strong></li>
      <ul>
        <h4>You can read more about this person here
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs" id="tribute-link" target="_blank">Wikipedia article</a>
        </h4>
  </section>


</main>
```

```
body{
  background-color: black;
}
#image{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;


}

h1,p,figcaption,h2,h4,li{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  

}
a{
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  
}
```

(https://mewni1.github.io/Tribute-page/)
[Picture on live server](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WnoVE2kCj1aan46hKHloLK3ZhF2HNOJo/view)
[Picture on live server](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cj5vClvWfoqjBudeIge9FbSRphB70yqX/view)
[Picture on github pages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15zXUjslX5pmG695aEkHBd-uxxkhR4Dv9/view)
[Picture on github pages](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5jD9vQHDhbdtjLUhjkFmqLRgtk2jbm6/view)

I tried changing the font size, the font should be bootstrap 5

Comment: Are you sure you pushed your changes to github? Also: when you commit, make sure the commit message contains [a decent description](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-better-git-commit-messages/) of the changes. ["styles.css"](https://github.com/Mewni1/Tribute-page/commits/main) is not a good commit message.

Answer (score -3):

The error was found, I changed the font size in the browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).